# libnfc write Bitcoin tag to be read on Android phone

Tags: nfc

I have libnfc working on my PN532 system and I can read a tag with utils/nfc-list.

How do I write a tag such as "bitcoin:myaddress?amount=1" that can be read by the usual Android Bitcoin wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utils/nfc-emulate-forum-tag4 can emulate a tag4 and it takes a ndef as input.